# Использовать HidD_GetHidGuid

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

Пытаюсь подключиться к USB камере. 
Использую функцию `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(libusb_context *ctx, uint16_t vendor_id, uint16_t product_id);` библиотеки `libusb`.

Когда вызываю эту функцию :

```
libusb_device_handle *devh = NULL;
uint16_t vendor_id = 0x04B4;
uint16_t product_id = 0x00C3;
try
{
    devh =  libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, vendor_id, product_id);
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    printf("%s", e.what());
}
```

получаю ошибку на нулевой адрес.

В Debug нашел причину, в файле `windows_winusb.с` функция `HidD_GetHidGuid(&hid_guid);  = NULL`

Как и где можно иницилизировать эту функцию? 
Спасибо.

Comment: libusb_init(NULL);
libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

Answer (score 1):

Надо было добавить :

```
libusb_init(NULL);
libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);
```